# Centos 7 No ejecuta Cron Jobs

Tags: script, centos

Tengo un inconveniente con la implementación de Cron Jobs en CentOS 7. Creé un Script para realizar el reinicio de un servicio y que este se ejecute de forma automática con una tarea programada en crontab. El problema es que los comandos del script no se están ejecutando, lo digo porque al validar los logs de cron muestra que la instrucción se ejecutó a la hora que indiqué, pero al validar el status del servicio  veo que el tiempo de activación no cambia y lo más curioso es que si ejecuto el script de forma manual funciona perfecto.

A continuación comparto el contenido de mi script y la estructura del cron job:

```
#!/bin/bash
service glassfish stop
sleep 360
service glassfish start

0 12 * * * root ./glassfish_restart.sh
```

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia al respecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada agradezco los aportes realizados por @luffy_064 y @Juanmhs.
El inconveniente se presentaba porque al momento de usar crontab -e los cambios no se realizaban sobre el archivo /etc/crontab. Entonces lo que hice fue programar la tarea directamente desde el archivo en cuestion y funciono perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo pudiera ser la ruta del script debes darle la ruta completa desde `/`, por ejemplo:

```sh
0 12 * * * root /home/user/script/glassfish_restart.sh
```

`/home/user/script/` debes remplazarlo por la ruta donde se encuentra tu script

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu sugerencia @Juanmhs

Comment: Te funciono de esa manera?

Comment: No funciona ¿Se te ocurre alguna otra cosa que pueda intentar?

Comment: Podría ser permisos chequea que el archivo tenga permisos de ejecución

Answer (score 0):

primero valida si realmente se esta invocando el `glassfish_restart.sh` , dentro del archivo realiza un simple print para validar.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello, world!'
```

en caso tu crontab, se este ejecutando correctamente, debes validar la variables de entorno de linux, sucede que el crontab solo cargar las variables minimas.

Comment: he realizado la modificación de acuerdo  a tu sugerencia y entiendo que la idea es que imprima en pantalla 'Hello, world!' lo cual no sucede. Configuré el cron job para que se ejecute cada minuto y si reviso el log veo que efectivamente registra el evento cada minuto.

Comment: Debo validar alguna variable de entorno en especifico?

Comment: en realidad lo primero que tienes que validar es el hello world, valida los permisos del archivo, tal vez el usuario que maneja el crontab no tenga permisos para ejecutar el archivo.